# SHA256 keeps creating same hash with different salt value

Tags: java, cryptography, sha256, salt

I wrote a simplified version of SHA256 algorithm and tried some inputs. At first it seems to work fine(although the output is a bit different from the online codes), but when I tried with input `"admin"`, it outputs the same hash regardless of salt String added to input. Surprisingly, if input is `"admi`", `"admin1"` or `"admin1234"`, it still outputs the same hash. I didn't find any other input that has the same problem.
Here's the code:

```java
package src.encrypt;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Password {
  private String salt;
  private String hash;

  private String saltGen() {
    final String hex = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    Random rnd = new Random(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    char[] salt = new char[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      int n = rnd.nextInt(hex.length());
      salt[i] = hex.charAt(n);
    }
    return String.valueOf(salt);
  }

  public Password() {
  };

  public Password(String pass) {
    salt = saltGen();
    String p = new String(pass + salt);
    hash = sha256(p);
  }

  public String getSalt() {
    return salt;
  }

  public String getHash() {
    return hash;
  }

  public boolean compareHash(String h) {
    return getHash().equals(sha256(h + getSalt()));
  }

  // SHA-256 Hashing Algorithm
  public String sha256(String str) {

    // Pre-processing
    ArrayList<String> hash = new ArrayList<>();
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bytes.length - 4; i += 4) {
      String tmp = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i] & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0')
          + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i + 1] & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0') +
          String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i + 2] & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0') +
          String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i + 3] & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0');
      hash.add(tmp);
    }
    String temp = new String();
    for (int j = i; j < bytes.length; j++)
      temp = new String(temp + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[j] & 0xff)).replace(' ', '0'));
    if (temp.length() < 32)
      temp = new String(temp + "10000000");
    while (temp.length() < 32)
      temp = new String(temp + "00000000");
    hash.add(temp);
    int l = 14 - hash.size() % 16;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
      hash.add(new String("00000000000000000000000000000000"));
    String tmp = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString((long) (bytes.length * 8))).replace(' ', '0');
    hash.add(tmp.substring(0, 32));
    hash.add(tmp.substring(32));

    // Init Hash values
    int H[] = {
        0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19
    };

    // Init Round Constants
    int K[] = {
        0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
    };

    // Create Message Schedule and Compressing
    l = hash.size() / 16;
    int a = H[0], b = H[1], c = H[2], d = H[3], e = H[4], f = H[5], g = H[6], h = H[7];
    ArrayList<Integer> w = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      for (int j = i * 16; j < (i + 1) * 16; j++) {
        w.add(Integer.parseInt(hash.get(j), 2));
      }
      for (int j = 16; j < 64; j++) {
        int s0 = rightRotate1(w.get(j - 15));
        int s1 = rightRotate2(w.get(j - 15));
        w.add(w.get(j - 16) + s0 + w.get(j - 7) + s1);
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
        int temp1 = h + rightRotate3(e) + ((e & f) ^ (~e & g)) + K[i] + w.get(i);
        int temp2 = rightRotate4(a) + ((a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c));
        h = g;
        g = f;
        f = e;
        e = d + temp1;
        d = c;
        c = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp1 + temp2;
      }
      // Modify final values
      H[0] = H[0] + a;
      H[1] = H[1] + b;
      H[2] = H[2] + c;
      H[3] = H[3] + d;
      H[4] = H[4] + e;
      H[5] = H[5] + f;
      H[6] = H[6] + g;
      H[7] = H[7] + h;
    }
    // Concatenate final hash
    String s = new String();
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      s = new String(s + String.format("%08X", H[i]).toLowerCase());
    }
    return s;
  };
  // right rotate
  private int rotr(int x, int n) {
    return (x >>> n) | (x << (32 - n));
  }

  private int rightRotate3(int x) {
    return rotr(x, 6) ^ rotr(x, 11) ^ rotr(x, 25);
  }

  private int rightRotate4(int x) {
    return rotr(x, 2) ^ rotr(x, 13) ^ rotr(x, 22);
  }

  private int rightRotate1(int x) {
    return rotr(x, 7) ^ rotr(x, 18) ^ x >>> 3;
  }

  private int rightRotate2(int x) {
    return rotr(x, 17) ^ rotr(x, 19) ^ x >>> 10;
  }
```

With input `"admin"`, output is always `"0920b401857e70a28c7b645c04195f2f15b54b98a7e7810f6d46c3a9c74adf6a"`
Can anyone spot some bugs or mistakes that I made?
Please note that I'm new to Java so some methods I use maybe unefficient.

**EDIT**
Here's how I call the method:

```java
// Main.java
import src.encrypt.Password;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pass = "admin";
    Password p = new Password(pass);
    System.out.println(p.getSalt()); // different calls, different values
    System.out.println(p.getHash()); // different calls, same value
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably show how you're calling that code. Of course if you use the empty ctor,  `salt` and `hash` will be left as null strings

Comment: @g00se I edited the question. Also the empty ctor is auto generated by vscode extension and I forgot to delete it.

Comment: Where to begin? [A] This code is _incredibly_ inefficient, doing all sorts of bizarre things (such as using string 'math' to concatenate binary prints instead of just processing the bytes as they are), and making pointless `new String` calls, [B] hashing passwords with SHA256 is a dumb thing to do. Use BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2, or any other password-specific hashing scheme, [C] Do not handroll your crypto algorithms. This one, for example, has timing attack vulnerabilities everywhere.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Sorry for the problems. I only write this for learning purpose to understand how it works, and I'm still learning PBKDF2, so I didn't make it that far. And as I said, I'm new to Java so inefficient is really unavoidable.

Comment: If you are doing it as a learning exercise, get rid of all the custom preprocessing that isn't teaching you anything good. SHA-256 works on a string of bytes. Just encode your text (using a specified `Charset` like `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`) to bytes and "learn" how SHA-256 works with that. Your problem might go away with that, but if the problem remains, at least people can focus on the stuff that matters instead of the strange string processing you are doing.

Comment: A good practice to learn is to never, ever do your own cryptography.

Comment: In any case, you should separate your SHA-256 implementation from any other processing. Then write tests on the SHA-256 algorithm using published "test vectors" and other known-good inputs and outputs. Basic divide and conquer debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs in the processing of the message schedule array (the `w` arraylist, the terminology is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2):

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
    int temp1 = h + rightRotate3(e) + ((e & f) ^ (~e & g)) + K[i] + w.get(i);
    int temp2 = rightRotate4(a) + ((a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c));
    h = g;
    g = f;
    f = e;
    e = d + temp1;
    d = c;
    c = b;
    b = a;
    a = temp1 + temp2;
  }
```

Your loop variable here is `j`, but you use the variable `i` to access the message schedule array (`i` is used in the outer loop that processes the message chunks).

The correct code is

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
    int temp1 = h + rightRotate3(e) + ((e & f) ^ (~e & g)) + K[j] + w.get(j);
    int temp2 = rightRotate4(a) + ((a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c));
    h = g;
    g = f;
    f = e;
    e = d + temp1;
    d = c;
    c = b;
    b = a;
    a = temp1 + temp2;
  }
```